# What is the correct stage to use for Google Guice in production in an application server?

Tags: java, performance, guice

It seems like a strange question (the obvious answer would Production, duh), but if you read the java docs:

```
/**
  * We want fast startup times at the expense of runtime performance and some up front error
 * checking.
 */
DEVELOPMENT,

/**
 * We want to catch errors as early as possible and take performance hits up front.
 */
PRODUCTION
```

Assuming a scenario where you have a stateless call to an application server, the initial receiving method (or there abouts) creates the injector new every call. If there all of the module bindings are not needed in a given call, then it would seem to have been better to use the Development stage (which is the default) and not take the performance hit upfront, because you may never take it at all, and here the distinction between "upfront" and "runtime performance" is kind of moot, as it is one call.

Of course the downside of this would appear to be that you would lose the error checking, causing potential code paths to cause a problem by surprise.

So the question boils down to are the assumptions in the above correct? Will you save performance on a large set of modules when the given lifetime of an injector is one call?

Comment: Is creating a new injector for every request really what you want to do?  It's not how we do it (modulo child injectors).

Comment: @Kevin, I'd be happy to hear about better options in the alternative. Note that the injector has a piece of state (an authentication token passed on the call) that has to be different on every call, so just storing it in a static is not an option. Although I know that Child Injectors exist, I never looked into what they can do for me.

Comment: Consider assisted inject? Or perhaps a SimpleScope with a seeded value? http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes

Comment: @Jesse, I used assisted Inject for something else, but it wouldn't apply here. SimpleScope is definitely cool (thanks, never thought of it before), but I don't see how it avoids creating the injector for each request - otherwise where do you store the injector, just in a static? Is that appropriate?

Comment: Use SimpleScope's seeded keys for the bindings that you can't satisfy until runtime. Inject your simple scope into the code that knows those values, and call enter/seed/exit at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no need to create an Injector for every request. That's not really how Guice is intended to be used - you should only need one Injector per application. An injector is really represents the configuration or wiring of an application, not a short-lived state.

I suspect you need to look into using [Guice Scopes](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes).

[GuiceServlet](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) provides you with `@RequestScoped` which allows you to limit the lifetime of an object to an HTTP request, which sounds like what you want to do.

If you're not in a Servlet, you can always define your own [custom scope](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes). It's not very complex.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but isn't a scope like @RequestScoped the same thing as creating the injector every time? Anyway, the solution I settled on was to create a child injector and indeed keep the Injector in a static. Not sure that is really 100% EJB spec, but it works.

Comment: In a limited way, yes it is. But using a child injector to control scope will limit you in other ways:  
1. You won't be able mix any other scopes in, so any @Singleton entities in the child injector will be dropped.  
2. You will have all the overhead of injector creation on every request, which can be significant. Part of the point of having a single injector is doing all the binding work up-front.